# Removing app from download queue in Amazon App Store

Tags: amazon-appstore

A few weeks ago I installed Amazon App Store and tried to download a game that was free for that one day. I "bought" it for free according to my Amazon account, but I've never been able to download it as the file size is large and download's wi-fi only. My wi-fi's very patchy so I've never been able to complete the download, apart from once when it said there was a "package error" after downloading.

I'm not even that bothered about downloading this game - I just wanted to check it out since it was free - so now I just want to get rid of it from my "My Apps" download queue. There seems to be no way I can find to just delete it. Anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Being unable to remove that one app in my download queue was mildly annoying, but today I noticed that every app I've downloaded from Amazon App Store and have since uninstalled is in that queue now. This happened after I was asked to sign back into my Amazon account via the app. It's ridiculous. I think I'll get rid of Amazon App Store and stick to Appbrain and the conventional Android market.

Answer (score 3):

Go to My apps-> cloud-> hold the app you want to remove (it is valid only for installed or downloaded apps not for paused ore ongoing download).

If you want to remove ongoing download, then you must cancel that. To cancel, you have to go to setting-> running apps-> amazon app store.

You will see 4-6 processes there. You have to stop download process from there. Note: the download process will only appear if that download is running at that time and it may take a few seconds to appear.

After stopping download process, when you will return to that app in app store's cloud section, you will see download cancelled. Now you can hold that entry and safely choose remove from upcoming box.

Answer (score 1):

I would try clearing the data for the Amazon Appstore via `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`.  You'll have to log into it again and whatnot the next time you open it, but hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: I think the question is more related to the download-able list of all purchased apps, not 'about to be downloaded' queue. Your answer would be correct if the question was actually about canceling a bunch of apps selected for download.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Yep, I based this on the phrase used by the OP.  His comment makes it more clear though.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's title does seem to imply the problem to which your solution applies.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot remove items you have "purchased" from this list. It keeps them on the amazon side, not on the device. I have wiped all data from my device, and once I reinstalled amazon app store, all of my purchased apps appeared in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove purchased apps by going to Amazon's website and viewing all of your apps. There is an option under `Actions` to `Delete this app`, which will remove it from your account. If you want it again, you will have to repurchase it.

This feature has been available for quite a while now (not sure when they added it; obviously after you asked the question).

Answer (score 0):

As of today I don't think this is possible.  You can however find the list of items on the Amazon website.

Log in to Amazon, click the "Your Digital Items" at the top right of the page, click "Your Apps & Devices".  From there you can see all of your app purchases.  Maybe some day they'll allow removing from the list.